# Category + lazy instantiation patterns on Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm trying to use a lazy instantiation on a category but I'm stuck on how to do that without enter in a obvious infinity loop. Here some code for ilustrate:

```
@implementation User (Extras)

- (CacheControl *)cache
{
    CacheControl *_cache = (CacheControl *)[self valueForKey:@"cache"];
    if(!_cache){
        [self setCache:(CacheControl *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CacheControl" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    }
    return _cache;
}
@end
```

Any Ideas how to address this situation or should I just don't do that at all?

Comment: Does `User` have a `cache` property?

Comment: I think we must assume so but the question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Yes it does, User has a cache property, the accepted answer from Martin R solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid infinite recursion in the getter method, you have to use the 
"primitive accessor" Core Data accessor methods:

```
- (CacheControl *) cache {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"cache"];
    CacheControl * cache = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"cache"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"cache"];

    if (cache == nil) {
        cache = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CacheControl" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:cache forKey:@"cache"];
    }
    return cache;
}
```

Similar examples can be found in the "Core Data Programming Guide" and in
the `sectionIdentifier` method of the ["Custom Section Titles with NSFetchedResultsController"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939-DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m-DontLinkElementID_6) sample project.